How to retrieve values ​from the layer property window via a script?
I can obtain via the property window the values: Upper Left / Lower Left / Upper Right / Lower Right for a non-georeferenced image.
How can we obtain these values ​​via a script for several hundred images of different sizes?
I don't know how to start. If someone can put me on a track...


If essentially you want to obtain the width and height of each image, then that is very simple:
import os

input_folder = 'Path\\to\\folder\\containing\\images'
for file in os.scandir(input_folder):
    f_path = os.path.join(input_folder, file.name)
    rl = QgsRasterLayer(f_path, '', 'gdal')
    if not rl.isValid():
        continue
    print(f_path)
    print(f'Image height: {rl.height()}')
    print(f'Image width: {rl.width()}')

